# POSIX timer with sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID method

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer, synchronization

In a multithreaded scenario, I am trying to implement a POSIX timer in which on timer expiration the next thread of the same process should be awakened (at a time only one thread is running and all others are in block state).
In the timer, I am using *sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID* as neither I want any handler to service the signal nor I want to create a new thread after the timer expiration .

```
//Import
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 10

#define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME

int ret;
//pthread_cond_t      condA[NUM_THREADS+1]  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t      condA  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t     mutex  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

sem_t sem[NUM_THREADS];
sem_t mute;

timer_t timer1;
pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
int state = 0;
int thread_count = 1;
int arr_tid[NUM_THREADS];
struct itimerspec new_value, old_value;

struct sigaction action;
struct sigevent sevent;
sigset_t set;
int signum = SIGALRM;

void *threadA(void *data_)
{
    cpu_set_t my_set;        
    CPU_ZERO(&my_set);       
    CPU_SET(2, &my_set);     
    sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &my_set);

    //struct itimerspec new_value, old_value;

    int i = 0, value;
    int sid;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ipc.out","a");    

    long int loopNum;
    int turn = (intptr_t)data_;
    struct timespec tval_result, tval_result2;

    if(thread_count < NUM_THREADS)
    {
        thread_count++;
        sid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
        arr_tid[turn] = sid;
        fprintf(fp,"thread_%d %d\n", turn, sid); 
        //printf("Blocked %d ->%d\n", turn, thread_count );
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&condA, &mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    else
    {
        arr_tid[turn] = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    }

    for (value = 0; value < NUM_THREADS; ++value)
    {   
        printf("%d\n",arr_tid[value] );
    } 
    //printf("rpg\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condA);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    //printf("unblocked\n");
    fclose(fp); 

    if (turn > 0)
        {
            if (sigwait (&set, &signum) == -1)
                perror ("sigwait");
            //sleep(1);
            //printf("thread %d is sleeping\n", turn);
        }
    while(1)
    {
        ret = sem_wait(&sem[turn]);
        if (ret)
        {
            printf("Error in Sem Post\n");
        }
        //printf("this isn't the end of the world!!!\n");
        sevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID;
        sevent._sigev_un._tid = arr_tid[(turn+1)%10];
        sevent.sigev_signo = signum;

        sigemptyset(&set);
        sigaddset(&set, signum);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

        printf("Thread # -> %d\n", turn);
        clock_gettime(CLOCKID, &tval_result);
        do
        {
            clock_gettime(CLOCKID, &tval_result2);  
        } while( (tval_result2.tv_sec - tval_result.tv_sec)*1000000000+(tval_result2.tv_nsec - tval_result.tv_nsec)<=12000);       
               //printf("Timestamp : %ld %ld\n", tval_result2.tv_sec, tval_result2.tv_nsec);
       // printf("Before creating timer\n");

        new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        new_value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
        new_value.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        new_value.it_value.tv_nsec = 15000;
        printf("next thread to be signalled %d\n", arr_tid[turn+1]);
        if (timer_settime (timer1, 0, &new_value, NULL) == -1)
            perror ("timer_settime");
        printf("yy\n");
        ret = sem_post(&sem[(state+1)%NUM_THREADS]);
        if (ret)
        {
            printf("Error in Sem Post\n");
        }
        state++; 
        //printf("yy\n");
        //sleep(1);
        if (sigwait (&set, &signum) == -1)
            perror ("sigwait");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data = 0;
    int err, i;
    int sid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    //struct itimerspec new_value, old_value;

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ipc.out","a");    
    fprintf(fp,"Mainthread %d\n",sid);  
    fclose(fp); 
    if (timer_create (CLOCK_REALTIME, &sevent, &timer1) == -1)
        perror ("timer_create");

    sem_init(&sem[0], 0, 1); 
    //sem_init(&sem[1], 0, 0); 
    //sem_init(&sem[2], 0, 0); 
    for ( i = 1; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        {
            sem_init(&sem[i], 0, 0); 
        }
    while(data < NUM_THREADS)
    {
        //create our threads
        err = pthread_create(&tid[data], NULL, threadA, (void *)(intptr_t)data);
        if(err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        data++;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

**Compilation:** *$ gcc filename.c -lrt -lpthread*

I have used semaphores to synchronize the threads so that threads execute in a particular sequence.

I am not getting the desired output. It should be like after 15 microseconds the timer should expire and next thread should be awakened but it's not happening. 
I have used **sigwait()** to block the threads. Are there any other alternatives to block a thread and awake them using a timer?
What are the signals that can be assigned in **signum**? Can I use pthread_cond_signal() instead of SIGALRM?

Comment: Seems a little pointless....

Comment: @MartinJames Well according to the sigwait() man page, any number of threads waiting for the signal can be picked up to serve the signal. Which is not desirable in my case. So, if there is some mechanism to specifically wake up a thread on timer expiration, then that will suffice for my problem. (like in pthread_cond_signal() where we can send signal to a particular thread waiting on a cond variable)

Answer (score 1):

Um.. OK.

Initialize your semaphore to one unit and have all the threads wait for it.

If a thread gets the unit, it stores the current 'startTime' time in some static/gobal/whatever, (safe, since only one thread can have the semaunit at a time), and goes away to do its thing/s.  When it's done, it gets the curent 'endTime' time, claculates how long it took as 'endTime-startTime' and subtracts that from the desired inter-thread interval time - now has how long is left before the next thread can go - 'remainingInterval'.  If remainingInterval is less than 0 it makes it 0.  It converts remainingInterval to whatever unit is required for usleep()/Sleep() and sleeps for that long, then sends its unit to the semaphore.  Another thread can then run, and the thread that just did its work can loop round and wait on the semaphore again, if it wishes.

It is just not possible for more than one thread to run at a time, no matter how long/sort/whatever the job/s take.

No explicit timer, mutex, condvar etc etc is required, just one semaphore.

Comment: Shrewdly written... The 'remainingInterval' that you have mentioned is desired to be 1 microsecond or even lesser. So, practically, I can't use sleep() or usleep(). Even if I go with clock_nanosleep(), I can't achieve that resolution in current processors(correct me if I'm wrong). So, I need some multithreaded mechanism to achieve that. I was hoping I could achieve that much fine granularity with timer.

Comment: 1 us?  You will be unable on any OS I know of.  I still don't uderstand why you need all those threads anyway - only one can run at a time, so why bother?

Comment: Okey, I am using multiple threads because the virtual runtime of each thread will be lesser than that of the process which will run in that 'remainingInterval'. All the threads are doing the same work one after another sequentially. This inter-thread duration (which I want around 1 us) should be reserved for a process on the same core. Thus, this whole set-up will be such that, as soon as one thread finishes it's job, it will go into block state. In the meanwhile, that other process will start executing for 1us. By this time next thread should be awakened by the timer (in my implementation).

Comment: Lesser the virtual runtime, higher the priority to get CPU time next (as red-black trees implementation of the kernel scheduling) and hence can preempt the current running process (that other same core resident process). The goal is to provide as much less time as possible to the other process (assuming only one) running on the same core with my multithreaded process.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting all threads to get signaled one at a time on timer expiry, in sequential fashion, but the timer setting (timer_settime) has been done in all threads, which breaks the rule.

**This is what needs to be done:**
The timer and the setting of time, needs to happen at the process level single time, and not per-thread.

Next, create all the threads, and store the thread-ids in an array, and make them wait based on some condition (pthread_cond_wait).

When the timer expires, and sends a signal, loop through the thread-ids and wake up, one thread at a time.

Comment: So, I'll have to create a signal handler for each thread to service the signal that comes after the expiry of timer right? Also, in that signal handler, I should use pthread_cond_signal() to awake the next thread waiting on a cond variable (if it is safe to call from handler). But I'm using SIGEV_THREAD_ID method so that the same running thread awake the next one hence no need to create a handler. Then how should I wake up the thread waiting on pthread_cond_wait()? Can I use pthread_cond_signal() instead of SIGALRM in my code?

Comment: I think you didn't get it. There will be single signal handler. The timer_create and timer_settime will happen just once in main(). Once the timer expires, and the signal handler catches it, inside that signal handler, you just need to find the next thread in sequence from your array of thread-ids and wake it up.